# How to use latest boost version in Travis CI?

Tags: c++, boost, travis-ci

I tried to install `boost 1.64` in Travis CI environment in several way. But none of them was succeeded. 
In my first naive attempt I just added following line in travis script:

```
install:
  - sudo apt-get install libboost1.64-all-dev
```

The result was error message: cannot find package libboost1.64-all-dev

In second attempt I specified repository with  necessary `boost` version.

```
before_install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nschloe/boost-nightly
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
install:
  - sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
  # - sudo apt-get install libboost1.64-all-dev (also tried)
```

In the first case default `boost` version (1.54) was installed.
In second case result was same error message: cannot find package libboost1.64-all-dev

In third attempt I manually typed instructions to install `boost`:

```
install:
  - sudo wget -O boost_1_64_0.tar.gz http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.64.0/boost_1_64_0.tar.gz/download
  - sudo tar xzvf boost_1_64_0.tar.gz
  - cd boost_1_64_0/
  - sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
  - sudo ./b2
  - sudo ./b2 install
```

As result my script took more than 30 min then was terminated.
Is any simple (or just working) way to install other than default boost version to Travis CI?

Comment: I don't think this is a Travis issue. "Manually" does it mean form the command line?

Comment: By manually I mean the same set of commands in Travis script that I would type in command line.

Comment: It definitely is a Travis issue that the latest version of many things they provide is from 2013, when the current year is about to be 2019.

Answer (score 6):

To look which all packages are available (esp. when you add the extra repository), you can run the "apt-cache search" command, e.g.:

```
sudo apt-cache search libboost
```

Then you can see the available versions.

When building manually, by default it builds "everything" (all static/shared debug/release libs), which then takes a lot of time and therefore it might timeout.

You can try to build only the libraries you actually need, for examle:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=program_options,filesystem,system
./b2 link=shared threading=multi variant=release
```

(see here for details: http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html)

Answer (score 6):

**Precompiled Boost**

Here are the steps I followed to get this to work:

1. Search on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) until I found a recent boost package build for the `trusty` environment.  That was non trivial, but there is a currently maintained ppa from `mhier` called `libboost-latest`
2. I found configuring the  `.travis.yml` correctly to use the ppa nontrivial, so I present a working snippet below which I hope will help  anyone else struggling with the same problem.

The following works for clang and gcc:

```
language: cpp
dist: trusty
sudo: false
os: linux

matrix:
  include:
    - env: COMPILER=g++-6 BUILD=Debug STANDARD=14
      compiler: gcc
      addons:
        apt:
          update: true
          sources:
            - sourceline: 'ppa:mhier/libboost-latest'
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - g++-6
            - boost1.67
    - env: COMPILER=g++-6 BUILD=Release STANDARD=14
      compiler: gcc
      addons:
        apt:
          update: true
          sources:
            - sourceline: 'ppa:mhier/libboost-latest'
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - g++-6
            - boost1.67
# the rest of your yaml file...
```

Hopefully mhier will keep this ppa running for a while, otherwise you'll have to go through step 1, or provide your own ppa.  As the boost version numbers progress the package number will change, so check the [ppa page](https://launchpad.net/~mhier/+archive/ubuntu/libboost-latest) to keep the package name up to date.

A complete working example can be found at the  [monstar github project](https://github.com/spacemoose/monstar).

**Compiling boost from source**
You can also compile boost from source within your travis build, although you run the risk of timing out.  The instruction for this are found in item 12 of boost's [best practice handbook](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/wiki/BestPracticeHandbook)

Comment: Where are the libraries saved? I don't know what to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR.

Comment: @NikosRenieris they should be in /usr/lib/

Comment: Note that the mhier builds only install shared libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same issue and limiting the informational output from the commands seemed to do the trick.

The three that flood the log:

```
    - tar -xzf boost_1_64_0.tar.gz
    - ./b2 -d0
    - ./b2 install -d0
```